# Twitter User Timeline json request without auth

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter

I was using the method of requesting a url and it returned a JSON with tweets expected.

Like this: https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/MyUserHere.json?callback=twitterCallback&count=2

But suddenly it stopped working. Returning only an error message.

Maybe I missed something in the twitter API. but from what I saw, now you must be logged in to request such data.

Have any way to call these tweets without exposing the user and password for my user?

Comment: Which error message is returning to you?

Comment: twittercallback({"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]});

Comment: Try to use proxy then see it gives you access or not

Comment: The question was answered. Is just put a "api." before the ".twitter.com". Shame on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter changed feed URL from   https://twitter.com to https://api.twitter.com/1/
So try below

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/MyUserHere.json?callback=twitterCallback&count=2

Sample feed url here

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codecocktail.rss

You can find more resource [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)